# SQLALchemy filter_by() on a foreign key producting weird sql

Tags: sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm attempting to filter on a foreign key and none of the SO answers I've searched for have lent any results.

Where are my query statements.

```
testing = Comments\
    .filter(Comments.post_id==post_id)
print(testing)

testing = Comments\
        .query.join(Post, aliased=True)\
        .filter(Comments.post_id==post_id)
print(testing)
```

Here's what my class definitions looks like

```
class Comments(db.Model):

    comment_id =  db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    post_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey("Post.post_id"),
        nullable=False)

class post(db.Model):
    post_id =  db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

Comments = db.relationship(
        'Comments',
        backref='Post',
        lazy='dynamic')
```

The actual SQL queries which are being produced from the first and second case. They both have this weird :post_id_1 thing. In both cases I'm getting a null set back.

```
FROM "Comments" 
WHERE "Comments".post_id = :post_id_1

FROM "Comments" JOIN "post" AS "post_1" ON "post_1".post_id = "Comments".post_id 
WHERE "Comments".post_id = :post_id_1
```

If I do a simple

`Select * from Comments where post_id = 1`

in the mysql CLI I get a result set.

Comment: The "wierd `:pst_id_1` thing" is called a bound parameter. You can view the actual query executed by passing `echo=True` to `create_engine`. Then there will be a statement which parameters have actually been passed. Thus you can see exactly what was queried. Use this to find out the difference between the queries.

Answer (score 0):

Your model definition is weird, the following part is not correctly indented:

```
Comments = db.relationship(
        'Comments',
        backref='Post',
        lazy='dynamic')
```

Or maybe it's just a copy/paste issue (just to be sure).

What you call "weird :esc_id_1 thing" is in fact an named placeholder. They will be replaced by the real value when the SQL statement will be executed (this is mainly to avoid SQL injection, the driver is responsible to escape values).

Comment: The indentation is syntactically correct, it's my prefered method to break up lines that are more than 80 characters long.


So every other sql statement is using `%s` followed by the variable lists. I said this was "weird" because it has no variable list and it's not the same sql as when I just filter_by(comment_id=commit_id). The weird part is that I get different sql statements depending on if I filter by a integer primary key or a integer foreign key.